# connecting multiple machines from C# windows application

Tags: c#, winforms, tcpclient

We have multiple Machines which can communicate via TCP/IP , each machine is in server mode unfortunately i cannot change the mode of the machine. Each one is having unique IP and port
i am trying to communicate with each machine using tcp client from a C# windows application. Each one when executed independently works good and returns value. The Basic communication code is provided by the vendor which is kind of event driven, whenever an event is happening the value is received. I am trying to create a single application to connect all the machines and receives the data from each one of them.The issue is only the first instance is getting connected and the next one is throwing error. In a gist how to connect multiple tcp server with distinct ip and port  in a single application simultaneously.

```
        tcpClient1 = new SimpleTcpClient();
        tcpClient2 = new SimpleTcpClient();
        tcpClient3 = new SimpleTcpClient();
        tcpClient4 = new SimpleTcpClient();
        tcpClient5 = new SimpleTcpClient();
```

like this i am trying. I know this is one of the dumbest idea, and definitely it is not working ,any help ??

EDIT

here is the error

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
> HResult=0x80004005
> Message=No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it xxx.xxx.0.1xx:4545
> Source=System
> StackTrace:
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
> at TourqueData.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in

and the code which starts and communicate with the machine is

```
tcpClient1.Connect(textIp.Text, (int)numericPort.Value);
        if (machine1.BeginCommunication(tcpClient1))
        {
            txtstatus.Text = "Connected";
            btnConnection.Text = "Disconnect";
            txtstatus.BackColor = Color.Green;
            m1Isconnected = true;
            var ret = MessageSubscribe(machine1, textIp.Text);
            if (ret == true)
            {
                machine1.AddUpdateOnReceivedCommand(typeof(xxxxx), OnTighteningReceived1);
            }
        }
```

The same set of code is replicated for other 4 connections. Here the first connection is get executed and it is subscribed to machine and receives data, others fail with the error above mentioned.
the connection is started via a button click event.

Each machine will have a button to connect.
[image]

the port number varies for each connection. Hope i am clear.

Comment: Maybe you can narrow it down. This machine (`xxx.xxx.0.1xx:4545`) seems to not accept the connection attempt. Do all the others behave the same way? Can you omit this machine an try the others? Could this be a firewall issue?

Comment: @JanKöhler, hi, each machine when connected individually works good and returns value, i.e. if i run separate instance of exe for each machine everything is good. What i need is a single exe which can communicate with all of them and get feedback. Hope i am clear

Comment: Sure, I understand. But it seems to me that you're just trying an all-or-nothing approach. What I suggest is extending the amount of instances step by step: Single instance - fine. All instances - doesn't work. So next, I'd try two instances. If this fails, too, try two other instances and so on. This way you can see, if it's a single instance that causes the failure or if it happens _always_ if there's more than one.

Comment: @JanKöhler did tried exactly as you suggested for 4 machines, the first one get connected with out any issues, rest always fails, if i run 4 instances of same exe with only one machine for each the data is coming without any issues